# how check multiple shiro permissions in database table?

Tags: java, shiro

I have `roles_perms` table as follow

```
id || username || role_name || perms_name
1      root         admin      page:show:*;folder:show:*
2      user1        editor     page:show:editorpage,page1;folder:show:folder45,folder55
```

but following line of code does not returns expected result.

```
// for user with role "admin"

System.out.println("Test 1 :"+SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("page:show:*")); // false
System.out.println("Test 2 :"+SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("page:show:*;folder:show:*")); // true

output:

Test1 :false
Test2 :true


// for user with role "editor"

System.out.println("Test 3 :"+SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("page:show:page1")); // false
System.out.println("Test 4 :"+SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("page:show:page1;folder:show:folder55")); // false 

 output:
 Test3 :false
 Test4 :false
```

**UPDATE:**

shiro.ini file

```
[main]
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.requiredType   = javax.sql.DataSource
ds.resourceName = jdbc/imgDB
ds.resourceRef = true
jdbcRealm = com.java.realm.MyRealm 

# 1000 ms = 1 sec
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 1800000 

# password hashing specification
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM shiro_users WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role_name FROM shiro_user_roles WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT perms_name FROM shiro_roles_perms WHERE role_name = ? AND username = ? 


jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.authorizationCachingEnabled = false

# specify login page 
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp 

# redirect after successful login
authc.successUrl = /home.jsp

# roles filter: redirect to error page if user does not have access rights
# perms filter: redirect to error page if user does not have permissions
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.jsp
perms.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.jsp

# request parameter with login error information; if not present filter assumes 'shiroLoginFailure'
# authc.failureKeyAttribute = simpleShiroApplicationLoginFailure

[urls] 

/login.jsp = authc
/admin/** = authc,roles[admin]
/editor/** = authc

# enable authc filter for all application pages
/ApacheShiroLogin/** = authc
```

Comment: How are you creating the `AuthorizationInfo`?

Comment: i am not creating my own AuthorizationInfo just using default one

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question. The title asks about getting values from a database table. However, the post uses the SercurityUtils object. Database table does not equal SecurityUtils.

If you want to select values from a database table. You need to specify what type of database you are using, the schema, etc. Then implement statements to select values from the database.

If you are trying to configure Shiro to use a database, please post you shiro configuration.

Please post your shiro configuration. That might give folks enough information to help you :)

Shiro must be configured to use a database.

Update:

In you Shiro configuration, tou need to add your realm to the security manager:

```
securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm
```

You also need to verify jndi lookups are configured properly.

Also, Please post the context of "but following line of code...". Have you submitted a valid login. If so, how? Where does the "line of code" reside? How is it being invoked??